# How to call custom function in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have defined a custom function to correct outliers of one of my DF column. The function is working as expected, but i am not getting idea how to call this function in DF. Could you please help me in solving this?

Below is my custom function:

```
def corr_sft_outlier(in_bhk, in_sft):
    bhk_band = np.quantile(outlierdf2[outlierdf2.bhk_size==in_bhk]['avg_sft'], (.20,.90))
    lower_band = round(bhk_band[0])
    upper_band = round(bhk_band[1])
    if (in_sft>=lower_band)&(in_sft<=upper_band):
        return in_sft
    elif (in_sft<lower_band):
        return lower_band
    elif (in_sft>upper_band):
        return upper_band
    else:
        return None
```

And i am calling this function in below ways, but both are not working.

1. outlierdf2[['bhk_size','avg_sft']].apply(corr_sft_outlier)
2. outlierdf2.apply(corr_sft_outlier(outlierdf2['bhk_size'],outlierdf2['avg_sft']))

Comment: Where do you want to store the value that the function returns?

Comment: I have one column created in same DF  outlierdf2['adj_avg_sft']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
outlierdf2['adj_avg_sft'] = df.apply(lambda x: corr_sft_outlier(x['bhk_size'],x['avg_sft']), axis=1)
```

Comment: I have followup question for above answer. I have defined one more function which takes only one parameter, in such case i am able to call function without passing argument, like this "df1.total_sqft.apply(convert_sqft_to_num)". Now, why my other function outlierdf2[['bhk_size','avg_sft']].apply(corr_sft_outlier) is not working however i selected 2 columns that are needed to pass to the function? Could you please explain this?

Comment: Can you post the full code? maybe in another question?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my reply, caught up with work. Will post the code today.

Comment: I have posted question as "Calling custom function in Pandas"